# Proving the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality using just only the field and order axioms

Tags: real-numbers

Using just the axioms, prove the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality:

$$\sqrt{ab}\leq\frac{a+b}{2}$$

for any $a, b \in\mathbb R$ with $a > 0$ and $b > 0$. (Assume, for the moment, the
existence of square roots.)

The only legal move I seem to be able to work from is the fact that since $a>0$ and $b>0$

then $a+b\gt0$

$a+b-b\gt-b\\
a\gt-b\\
a.b\gt-b.b$

Comment: Usually from $a>0,b>0$ follows both sum and product >0, i.e. $a+b>0$ AND $ab>0.$ Do you have the product closure $ab>0$ available to use? [In short, how is $<$ defined in your text/axioms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $\big(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\big)^2\geq0$.

EDIT: Supposing that your comment is asking "Where the hint comes from?"

We work backwards, from what we want:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{ab}\leq \frac{a+b}{2}&\implies 2\sqrt{ab}\leq a+b\\
&\implies 0\leq a+b-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}\\
&=a-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}+b\\
&=\sqrt{a}^2-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{b}^2
\end{aligned}.
$$
From here we must simply recognise this as a difference of two squares.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I can see the path to completing the proof from the hint you've given, but can you help me see how I get to the statement in your hint?

Comment: Do you mean "How would you have  known to use $(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)^2\geq 0$?"